# How firefox fetches correct data from Browser Cache

Tags: firefox, browser-cache, framebuffer, data-access

Once we open a link in a new tab in Firefox, the data corresponding to that web page(static or dynamic) gets stored in Browser Cache. Then, when we switches at that tab again, it extracts data of that page from Cache(not requesting from the server of that site) and paints it at the frame buffer of the screen.

I want to know that how Firefox fetches this data in correct sequence?

What kind of mapping does the Firefox uses to extract the page data from its Cache?

Answer (score 0):

Firefox (like any other browser) uses heuristics to decide when and what to cache. This is assuming no caching information is included in the resources. When no caching information is provided, Firefox might still decide to cache the files for certain period of time.

If you want to avoid Firefox to cache your resources altogether, you must include the following response header on your resources:

```
Cache-Control:no-cache, no-store
```

Now, the exact algorithm that Firefox uses to fetch from cache I don't think is public. Maybe somebody from Mozilla is able to answer this.